# Having problem while applying limit to a sin function by first principle method.

Tags: calculus, derivatives, trigonometry

The sin function applying limit is:

$$\lim _{\delta x\to 0 }\left(\frac{\sin \left(x+\frac{\delta x}{2}\right)\delta x}{\left(x+\frac{\delta x}{2}\right)\delta x}\right)$$

The solution which i have shows me that this whole function will be equal to '1', because of the limit formula of Sin Trigonometry Function, which is:

$$\lim _{x\to 0}\:\frac{\sin \left(x\right)}{x}\:=1$$

I cannot understand how we can use this formula in the original question, where there is $$(x+\frac{\delta x}{2})$$ in between.

Comment: The way you've written it, $x$ and $\delta x$ are completely independent of each other, and in fact$$\lim_{\delta x\to0}\frac{\sin\left(x+\frac{\delta x}{2}\right)\delta x}{\left(x+\frac{\delta x}{2}\right)\delta x}=\begin{cases}\frac{\sin x}{x},& x\neq0,\\1&x=0.\end{cases} $$Perhaps this is what you want to show? If you clarify on this I'll consider writing an answer